# Use groovy to get github tags for a private repo

Tags: github, groovy

I am trying to get all the tags from a private repo with private key, and I know for sure the key can connect, and I do have tags, but the print message is always empty, is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Thanks

```
def gettags = ('git ls-remote -t git@github.com:test/test.git').execute(['GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i /home/jenkins/.ssh/test.pem'], null)

println gettags.text
```

If I run command

`GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /home/jenkins/.ssh/test.pem" git ls-remote -t git@github .com:test/test.git`

I will get:
`a8f163eb67660f84d9e56eb21b775d33220222be   refs/tags/0.1`

Comment: Most likely the execute fails (using .execute on string instead of a list is already a bad omen). What return code do you get, what's on stderr?

Comment: pure empty. I get nothing.

Comment: An exit code an not be "empty".

Comment: I println `gettags.exitValue()` shows `128`

Comment: So unless it's 0, there is an error. Check the stderr and most likely you will see a clear description of the problem.